# how to hide Custom Scroll buttons based on items in Div block

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a array of `20 items`. In UI, I have two buttons and the 20 items. My UI looks like this.
[image]

When Clicking the `Prev` and `Next` Buttons, it scrolls correctly. 
But now my need was.
When the `div` block reaches `1st item`, i want to hide the `prev` button and show only `Next` button. Same as like when i reach last `20th item`, i want to hide `next` button and show only `Prev` Button. In between `div`, i want to show two buttons. 
I tried but don't know how to achieve it. Please Help with some soltions.

Here's the Code i tried:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const cardsContainerRef = useRef();
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
  const onPrevorNextBtnClick = (scrollOffset) => {
    cardsContainerRef.current.scrollLeft += scrollOffset;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "10px" }}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            onPrevorNextBtnClick(-300);
          }}
        >
          Prev
        </button>
        <div
          ref={cardsContainerRef}
          style={{ display: "flex", gap: "10px", overflow: "hidden" }}
        >
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              style={{
                width: "100px",
                height: "100px",
                flexShrink: 0,
                backgroundColor: "green",
                color: "white"
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            onPrevorNextBtnClick(300);
          }}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-morning-ziweui?file=/src/App.js 
Required Output:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intersection Observer (IO) for this. With IO you can observe an element and react whenever it comes into view (or leaves the view)

So you set up IO on your first and last element and whenever they are entering or leaving the view you add / remove a class that shows or hides the button.

I created a basic snippet where you can see the approach. You will have to add your logic to show / hide the buttons accordingly. I also only log when element is becoming visible, if you want to react for when it comes out of the view you have to add this too to the callback function.

```js
let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('ul'),
  threshold: 0.9
}
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
   if (entry.isIntersecting) {
     console.log(`${entry.target.className} is intersecting`);
   }
  });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);


let targets = document.querySelectorAll('li:first-child, li:last-child');

targets.forEach(target => {
 observer.observe(target);
})
```

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  gap: 10px;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
flex: 200px;
min-width: 200px;
height: 150px;
background: #b00b15;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li class="first">
 Test 
</li>

<li>
 Test 
</li>

<li>
 Test 
</li>

<li class="last">
 Test 
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the next button you can add a condition on it to be hidden when you are at [data.length -1] .

for the the previous button you can add a condtion on it to be hidden when you are not at data[0]

here my example and it's work for me :

```
    <button type="button" class="cursor-pointer" (click)="carrouselPrevAction()"
            *ngIf="!carrouselItems[0].active && carrouselItems.length> carrouselCards">
          </button>

 <button type="button" class="cursor-pointer" (click)="carrouselNextAction()"
            *ngIf="!carrouselItems[carrouselItems.length - 1].active && carrouselItems.length> carrouselCards">
          </button>



 carrouselPrevAction() {
    const index = this.carrouselItems.findIndex((element: any) => element.active == true)
    this.carrouselItems[index - 1].active = true;
    this.carrouselItems[index + this.carrouselCards - 1].active = false;
  }

  carrouselNextAction() {
    const index = this.carrouselItems.findIndex((element: any) => element.active == true)
    this.carrouselItems[index].active = false;
    this.carrouselItems[index + this.carrouselCards].active = true;
  }
```